# What is the true Legend of Zelda timeline?

Tags: time-travel, timeline, the-legend-of-zelda

Is the claimed historical sequencing of events as outlaid [here](https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--1fFdm3x---/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/18j0yyebco7eqjpg.jpg) in the correct order? This question assumes an in-depth knowledge of The Legend of Zelda franchise.

My understanding of the timeline is this (please correct me if wrong):

[image]

I'm just trying to understand the story, so at the β<sub>1</sub> junction Link carries out the events, presumably first, that lead up to the β<sub>1</sub>'' junction where he then travels back in time to β<sub>1</sub> to carry out the events leading up to the β<sub>1</sub>' junction? Do I have that right?

It would just be nice to have a theoretically plausible explanation as to how the timeline could be manifested in such a way that it is inline with the historical storyline of the franchise.

---

Here is another rendition of the timeline I made with the help of more clarification from the commenters (Right? Wrong?):

[image]

To be clear:

```
[α-β line]
    -skyward sword
    -the minish cap
    -four swords
    -ocarina of time
[β-β0 line]
    -a link to the past
    -oracle of ages
    -oracle of seasons
    -link's awakening
    -the legend of zelda
    -the adventure of link
[β-β1 line]
    -ocarina of time final cut scene
[β1-β1 loop]
    -adult link from ocarina of time sent back in time
[β1-β1' line]
    -majora's mask
    -twilight princess
    -four swords adventures
```

> ```
> [β1'-β1'' wave]
>     -yeah, not sure... the official timeline suggest that there was an option to be a child or adult (need some clarity here)
> [β1''-present]
>     -yeah, just guessing here.
> ```

---

Here is yet another rendition of the timeline with further clarification,  with the exception of not knowing the structure of events in the purple dotted region:

[image]

To be clear:

```
[ω-α line]
    -skyward sword
    -the minish cap
    -four swords
[α-α0 line]
    -ocarina of time (child)
[α0-α1 wave]
    -ocarina of time (link's hibernation)
[α1-β line]
    -ocarina of time (adult)
[β-β0 line]
    -a link to the past
    -oracle of ages
    -oracle of seasons
    -link's awakening
    -the legend of zelda
    -the adventure of link
[β-β1 line]
    -ocarina of time final cut scene
[β1-α bend]
    -adult link from ocarina of time sent back in time
[α-β1' line]
    -majora's mask
    -twilight princess
    -four swords adventures
```

> ```
> [β1'-β1'' wave]
>     -yeah, not sure... the official timeline suggest that there was an option to be a child or adult (need some clarity here)
> [β1''-present]
>     -yeah, just guessing here.
> ```

Notice that this timeline makes the statement that, relative to α, the future sealing of the Ocarina-of-Time Ganon[dorf] somehow changes the way that people live their lives and build their world in the second life of the non-Ocarina-of-Time Link's world. And, also, this would mean that the non-Ocarina-of-Time Ganon[dorf] *remembers* the Ocarina-of-Time events because somehow time travel doesn't undo the seal. Right?

---

[image]

---

**Universe 1:**

[image]

**Universe 2:**

[image]

**Pretty Version:**

[image]

Comment: I would also like to note that it’s *possible* that this question might fall afoul of rules about questions asking for scientific explanations, or whether something could “really happen.” There’s time travel in Hyrule; it works in Hyrule. Whether it could happen in the boring, magic-free real world is not the sort of question we generally answer.

Comment: physics->scifi->x

Comment: The physics stack told you to sent this to our site?

Comment: What is the next site, _i.e._ "x", that I should ask this at?

Comment: [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) sometimes takes questions about the plausibility of scientific mechanisms, but I suspect they wouldn’t like a question so closely tied to a fictional universe. If it were this specific and it were a world *you* were creating, that might be something else, but as it is I suspect they might not take it. You’d have to ask them, though. Another option might be to acquire 20 reputation, upon which you’ll be able to discuss this in our [chat] or that of Worldbuilding with any interested parties.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/204851/73976). The timeline released by Nintendo should clarify it a bit

Comment: I don't understand how this is off-topic.  It's specifically about the _Legend of Zelda_ series, and is completely explainable in-universe.

Comment: If you're looking for an explanation of the events of the game, it's ok. You remove those parts of the question asking for a real-world explanation - it'll keep the close votes at bay.

Comment: @Izkata - Because it is *specifically* asking for an explanation in terms of real-life science, including some  that I am pretty sure does not show up in Zelda.

Comment: do not show up*

Comment: Could you edit this question to ask about just the timeline? All that stuff about cloning and cryogenesis definitely makes this a real-world science question.

Comment: I edited out the bit about Futurama because it didn't seem particularly relevant to the reworked question.

Comment: Are Link, Zelda, and Ganon, etc. all simultaneous reincarnates?

Comment: @Domemy IIRC, officially Link and Zelda are reincarnations, but Ganon[dorf] is resurrected

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/204851/73976) about the Nintendo's official LoZ timeline

Comment: @Gorchestopher H, this is me saying hi.

Answer (score 5):

Your fork is (sort of) in the wrong place.

The child-success path is created in the final cutscenes of the game, when Ganondorf never rises to power.

The adult-success path is the timeline in which you played through at the end of the game, before that cutscene.

The failure path is essentially a do-nothing path, and occurs mid-game.  I generally think of it as occurring in the adult timeline, since otherwise it's indistinguishable with the other paths due to ancestry.  It occurs any point when Link has to travel back to the past and do something; the future he leaves has been abandoned to Ganondorf's rule.  The alterations made while temporarily in the past fork the timeline and result in returning to a slightly different future, where the adult-success timeline occurs.

Comment: I've made an edit to my post.

Comment: @Domemy Your current diagram pretty much fits what I'm describing here.  I'm just not using the word "defeated" for the failure branch, since that doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? He's defeated, then some other hero reincarnate carries out the events in the `[β-β0 line]`, and then the whole idea is that there are two parallel universes: The one where he was defeated and reincarnated, and the one where he goes back in time... I think...

Comment: @Domemy There's only 1 hero in _Ocarina of Time_ whose been crossing time/timelines, so him being simultaneously defeated and succeeding doesn't really make sense.  My answer doesn't have him defeated in any way, but includes the creation of a "failure" timeline where Link just vanishes.  This answer describes all 3 timelines existing in parallel, created from the one game.

Comment: Like the two universes I have in my updated post?

Comment: @Domemy No.  I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "universe", but I'm describing either 1 universe with 3 timelines, or 3 universes with 1 timeline.  The finale isn't the only time travel to the past in the game; there's also at least the Lens of Truth and the entrance to the Spirit Temple.  Those are when I think the "failure" path was created.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, no. There are multiple problems with this idea, but I guess the biggest problem is the timeline leading up to the very first games.

These require Link to fail in Ocarina of Time. But by doing so he won't be able to travel to the future for obvious reasons. Before failing, this future doesn't exist. Cloning is no solution since that would explain away everything and it's not really different from reincarnation (official timeline explanation).

In addition, there are other problems, just a few examples:

- Link is growing up in several games, not knowing about him being a hero.
- Link almost never starts with his equipment. He doesn't use SkyNet travelling naked, right?
- Several games mention the main characters being reborn throughout history. This might be perception by commoners, but even Ganondorf explains this once (not sure if considered canon since I think it was cut content from OoT).